# Supabase Spotify API request

Tags: javascript, django, spotify, supabase

I'm trying to create a Django app that uses Supabase to authenticate and log into spotify. i do so using the view:

```
def spotify_auth(request):

    # Redirect the user to Supabase's OAuth authentication endpoint
    data = supabase_client.auth.sign_in_with_oauth({
                "provider": 'spotify',
                
                "redirectTo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000//callback/",
                   
    })
    
    auth_url = data.url

    return redirect (auth_url)
```

this redirects me to a url like: http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/#access_token=
which is my home page. From my home page i want to be able to redirect to /top-tracks whilst maintaining the access token so i save it to session like so:

```
// Get the fragment URL from the current URL
const fragmentUrl = window.location.hash;

// Parse the fragment URL to extract key-value pairs
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(fragmentUrl.substring(1));

// Extract and save each piece of data
const access_token = urlParams.get('access_token');

// Save the extracted data to localStorage (or sessionStorage if needed)
localStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
```

I have a button to redirect to /top-tracks and in my top-tracks.html i have a script:

```
<script>

const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
console.log("access token:",access_token)

const getTopTracks = async () => {

  const url = new URL('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks');
  url.searchParams.append('time_range', 'short-term');
  url.searchParams.append('limit', '20');

  const response = await fetch(url,{
    method:'GET',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
} 

getTopTracks();


</script>
```

When the script is run I get

(index):39     GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=short-term&limit=20 401

What have I done wrong?

edit: i tried using the provider_token instead of access_token and get a 403 error

edit 2: added the scope and get the error
api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=short-term&limit=20:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at getTopTracks ((index):47:31):

```
    def spotify_auth(request):

        # Redirect the user to Supabase's OAuth authentication endpoint
        data = supabase_client.auth.sign_in_with_oauth({
                    "provider": 'spotify',
                    "scopes": 'user-top-read',
                    "redirectTo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000//callback/",
                       
        })
        
        auth_url = data.url

        return redirect (auth_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

`provider_token` is the correct token to use here, so you are correct with using the `provider_token` instead of `access_token`. The reason why you are getting 403 error is probably because [you don't have the scope to access the requested data](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/1118). Double-check the scope you are requesting.

```py
data = supabase.auth.sign_in_with_oauth({
  "provider": 'spotify',
  "options": {
    "scopes": 'user-top-read',
    'redirect_to': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback/',
  }
})
```

https://supabase.com/docs/reference/python/auth-signinwithoauth

Comment: ive added the scope and still get the 403 error but i am able to hit the /me endpoint

Comment: @KevinL You seem to have the wrong syntax for requesting scopes and specifying `redirect_to`. I have updated my response to include a sample code.